# Migrate with constructor parameters in Truffle

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

So basically I'm not quite sure how I can get my parameters from my solidity code and pass them in the deploy function of the deployer for my 2nd migration with Truffle.

This is the constructor of my Solidity code:

```
constructor(
    IBEP20 _stakeToken,
    IBEP20 _rewardToken,
    uint256 _rewardPerSecond,
    uint256 _startTimestamp,
    uint256 _bonusEndTimestamp
) public {
    stakeToken = _stakeToken;
    rewardToken = _rewardToken;
    rewardPerSecond = _rewardPerSecond;
    startTimestamp = _startTimestamp;
    bonusEndTimestamp = _bonusEndTimestamp;
    // staking pool
    poolInfo.push(PoolInfo({
    lpToken: _stakeToken,
    allocPoint: 1000,
    lastRewardTimestamp: startTimestamp,
    accRewardTokenPerShare: 0
    }));
    totalAllocPoint = 1000;
}
```

Then this is my javascript migration code:

```
const tokenstaking = artifacts.require("TokenStaking");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(tokenstaking, stakeToken, rewardToken, rewardPerSecond, startTimestamp, 
bonusEndTimestamp);};
```

Each time I receive the same error for all parameters:

```
ReferenceError: stakeToken is not defined
```

How can I reference my parameters? help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for parameters you have to pass values. You defined constructor before with parameters. `stakeToken, rewardToken, rewardPerSecond, startTimestamp,  bonusEndTimestamp`. Now you are initalizing the contract, so you have to pass arguments meaning that inital values.

So you have to get values of `stakeToken, rewardToken, rewardPerSecond, startTimestamp,  bonusEndTimestamp` and pass it

```
deployer.deploy(tokenstaking, 
   "getStakeToken",  // stakeToken 
   "getRewardToken", //rewardToken, 
   "1", // 1 reward per second
   "92389424982",//startTimestamp 
    "99239323232"//bonusEndTimestamp
```